# Retrieve data from drop down menu

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a drop down menu but something is wrong. It appears to not hold the data when I choose a matric number. I put a value, for example `2012456824`, in the textbox, then the data comes out but when I didn't put a value the data also comes out.

What could be causing this?

**dropdownmenu.html**

```
<form action="searchbook2.php" method="post">
          <font color=black>Search By : </font>
          <select name="choose">
               <option selected="selected">-Please Choose-</option>
               <option value="matricNo">Matric No.</option>
               <option value="bookAccession">Accession No.</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" name="search">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search" style="background:#996699"><br><br>
</form>
```

**searchbook2.php**

```
<?php
echo "<center><br><br>";

$choose = $_POST['choose'];
if($choose == 'matricNo'){
$search = $_POST['search'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT b.book_Accession, b.patron_ID, p.patron_Name, b.book_Title, b.book_Status

                    FROM book b
                    INNER JOIN patrons p 
                    ON b.patron_ID = p.patron_ID
                    WHERE b.patron_ID LIKE '%$search%'");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
 while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $patron_ID = $data['patron_ID'];
    echo "<br><br><table width='486' height='314' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' >";
    echo "<tr><td colspan=2 align=center bgcolor=gray>Loan Item</td></tr>";

    echo "<td width='200'>&nbsp;Patron Id : </td><td width='473'>".$data['patron_ID']."</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;Patron Name : </td><td>".$data['patron_Name']."</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Accession : </td><td>".$data['book_Accession']."</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Title : </td><td>".$data['book_Title']."</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Status : </td><td>".$data['book_Status']."</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo '<td colspan="2" align=center><a href="bookDetail.php?patron_ID=' . $data['patron_ID'] . '"
    onClick="javascript:return confirm(\'Do you want see this information ?\')">Click Here</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<br><Br><br>";
 }
 }

}else if($choose == 'bookAccession'){
$search = $_POST['search'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT  b.book_Accession, b.patron_ID, p.patron_Name, b.ISBN, b.book_Title, b.book_Author, b.book_Status, b.book_Year,
                    b.book_Category 

                    FROM book b
                    INNER JOIN patrons p 
                    ON b.book_Accession = p.book_Accession
                    WHERE b.book_Accession LIKE '%$search%'");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
 while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $book_Accession = $data['book_Accession'];

    echo "<table width='486' height='314' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' >";
    echo "<tr><td colspan=2 align=center bgcolor=gray>Book Information</td></tr>";

    echo "<td width='200'>&nbsp;Accession No. : </td><td width='473'>".$data['book_Accession']."</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;Patron Id : </td><td>".$data['patron_ID']."</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;Patron Name : </td><td>".$data['patron_Name']."</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Isbn : </td><td>".$data['ISBN']."</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Title : </td><td>".$data['book_Title']."</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Author : </td><td>".$data['book_Author']."</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Status : </td><td>".$data['book_Status']."</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Year : </td><td>".$data['book_Year']."</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Category : </td><td>".$data['book_Category']."</td>";

}
 echo "</table>";
 echo "<br><br>";
 }
 }
 else{
 echo "Sorry the data you have been search is not available";
 }
?>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific of what the current code is doing and your expected output

Comment: Don't use SQL, it's deprecated, Look into sqli or PDO prepared statements, They're safer against sql injection. I think you've missed a nested select, font tag also deprecated as of html4.Try putting`if(!empty($_POST['search']){$search = $_POST['search'];}

Comment: On a side note, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and all input from a user should be sanitized before being used in sql queries.

Comment: To Amir : the current code do is it search matric no data but I had a problem where when I put a wrong data then data also will be display..

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you do not validate the `$_POST['search']`. So if its empty, your query will be like this: `WHERE b.patron_ID LIKE '%%'"` what will give you back all records from your database.

```
if (!empty($search)) {
    //Show the table
} else {
    echo 'Plase provide a search condition!';
}
```

And escape your string with `mysql_real_escape_string`, if you do like this to avoid SQL injection, but the best if you use mysqli_* functions or PDO, because mysql_* functions are deprecated.

**UPDATE:**

Here you go.

```
<?php
echo "<center><br><br>";

$choose = $_POST['choose'];
if ($choose == 'matricNo') {
    $search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
    if (!empty($search)) { //<---- HERE IS A CHECK
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT b.book_Accession, b.patron_ID, p.patron_Name, b.book_Title, b.book_Status
                    FROM book b
                    INNER JOIN patrons p 
                    ON b.patron_ID = p.patron_ID
                    WHERE b.patron_ID LIKE '%$search%'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
            while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                $patron_ID = $data['patron_ID'];
                echo "<br><br><table width='486' height='314' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' >";
                echo "<tr><td colspan=2 align=center bgcolor=gray>Loan Item</td></tr>";

                echo "<td width='200'>&nbsp;Patron Id : </td><td width='473'>" . $data['patron_ID'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                echo "<td>&nbsp;Patron Name : </td><td>" . $data['patron_Name'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Accession : </td><td>" . $data['book_Accession'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Title : </td><td>" . $data['book_Title'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Status : </td><td>" . $data['book_Status'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                echo '<td colspan="2" align=center><a href="bookDetail.php?patron_ID=' . $data['patron_ID'] . '"
    onClick="javascript:return confirm(\'Do you want see this information ?\')">Click Here</a></td>';
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";
                echo "<br><Br><br>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        //This happens if no search criteria given
        echo "Please provide a search condition";
    }
} else if ($choose == 'bookAccession') {
    $search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
    if (!empty($search)) { //<---- HERE IS A CHECK
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT  b.book_Accession, b.patron_ID, p.patron_Name, b.ISBN, b.book_Title, b.book_Author, b.book_Status, b.book_Year,
                    b.book_Category 

                    FROM book b
                    INNER JOIN patrons p 
                    ON b.book_Accession = p.book_Accession
                    WHERE b.book_Accession LIKE '%$search%'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
            while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                $book_Accession = $data['book_Accession'];

                echo "<table width='486' height='314' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' >";
                echo "<tr><td colspan=2 align=center bgcolor=gray>Book Information</td></tr>";

                echo "<td width='200'>&nbsp;Accession No. : </td><td width='473'>" . $data['book_Accession'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                echo "<td>&nbsp;Patron Id : </td><td>" . $data['patron_ID'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                echo "<td>&nbsp;Patron Name : </td><td>" . $data['patron_Name'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Isbn : </td><td>" . $data['ISBN'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Title : </td><td>" . $data['book_Title'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Author : </td><td>" . $data['book_Author'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Status : </td><td>" . $data['book_Status'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Year : </td><td>" . $data['book_Year'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Category : </td><td>" . $data['book_Category'] . "</td>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
            echo "<br><br>";
        }
    } else {
        //This happens if no search criteria given
        echo "Please provide a search condition";
    }
} else {
    echo "Sorry the data you have been search is not available";
}
?>
```

Comment: where should i put this one?

Comment: everywhere where you create a query.

Comment: it's much more better, if your are try to understand what i did (because you will learn only on this way), instead of to wait for a code to copy/paste. today i am in a good mood, this is why i posted you the complete code ;)

Comment: Its work! However, when I search for example 2 then all of the data in database comes out.. Why ?

Comment: Ok. I do not know, i do not see your data in your database. Try to `print` your `$sql` and run in the mysql directly, and check, is the `b.patron_ID` or `b.book_Accession` has any record what has no contains the 2.

Comment: I think my html is wrong.. When i try 2 search a wrong data, all data have come out. I need to hold a value from textbox..

Comment: Ok, i hope you can solve your problem now. Anyway, there is not necessarry to create the `$choose` and `$search` variables, you can use directly the `$_POST['choose']` and `$_POST['search']` variables, if you do not want to manipulate them. It's unnecessary to reserve memory for them.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all use mysqli/PDO because mysql will be deprecated in future PHP versions
2. Always check if your POST or GET parameters are not null and if they are null provide an error message or a warning

I have edited the code to check the if `$_POST['search']` is null or not.

```
    <?php
    echo "<center><br><br>";
    if($_POST['search']!=null)// This line checks if your POST parameter search is null or not.
    {
        $choose = $_POST['choose'];
        if($choose == 'matricNo'){
            $search = $_POST['search'];
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT b.book_Accession, b.patron_ID, p.patron_Name, b.book_Title, b.book_Status

                FROM book b
                INNER JOIN patrons p 
                ON b.patron_ID = p.patron_ID
                WHERE b.patron_ID LIKE '%$search%'");

            if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
               while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                $patron_ID = $data['patron_ID'];
                echo "<br><br><table width='486' height='314' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' >";
                echo "<tr><td colspan=2 align=center bgcolor=gray>Loan Item</td></tr>";

                echo "<td width='200'>&nbsp;Patron Id : </td><td width='473'>".$data['patron_ID']."</td>";
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                echo "<td>&nbsp;Patron Name : </td><td>".$data['patron_Name']."</td>";
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Accession : </td><td>".$data['book_Accession']."</td>";
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Title : </td><td>".$data['book_Title']."</td>";
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Status : </td><td>".$data['book_Status']."</td>";
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                echo '<td colspan="2" align=center><a href="bookDetail.php?patron_ID=' . $data['patron_ID'] . '"
                onClick="javascript:return confirm(\'Do you want see this information ?\')">Click Here</a></td>';
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";
                echo "<br><Br><br>";
            }
        }

    }else if($choose == 'bookAccession'){
        $search = $_POST['search'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT  b.book_Accession, b.patron_ID, p.patron_Name, b.ISBN, b.book_Title, b.book_Author, b.book_Status, b.book_Year,
            b.book_Category 

            FROM book b
            INNER JOIN patrons p 
            ON b.book_Accession = p.book_Accession
            WHERE b.book_Accession LIKE '%$search%'");

        if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
           while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $book_Accession = $data['book_Accession'];

            echo "<table width='486' height='314' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' >";
            echo "<tr><td colspan=2 align=center bgcolor=gray>Book Information</td></tr>";

            echo "<td width='200'>&nbsp;Accession No. : </td><td width='473'>".$data['book_Accession']."</td>";
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            echo "<td>&nbsp;Patron Id : </td><td>".$data['patron_ID']."</td>";
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            echo "<td>&nbsp;Patron Name : </td><td>".$data['patron_Name']."</td>";
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Isbn : </td><td>".$data['ISBN']."</td>";
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Title : </td><td>".$data['book_Title']."</td>";
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Author : </td><td>".$data['book_Author']."</td>";
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Status : </td><td>".$data['book_Status']."</td>";
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Year : </td><td>".$data['book_Year']."</td>";
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            echo "<td>&nbsp;Book Category : </td><td>".$data['book_Category']."</td>";

        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<br><br>";
    }
}
else{
   echo "Sorry the data you have been search is not available";
}
}
else
{
    echo 'Search keyword is blank';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Its work but I had a problem to hold a value from search.. For example when I write wrong data it will display all the data in my database. Can you help me to hold the value from the textbox

Comment: You mean when you give a wrong search keyword( which is not in the database), it gives results?

Comment: Yes that what I mean.

Comment: It will be better if you update the question, with the wrong search keyword and the results it is showing.

Comment: I think my html wrong.. It must be something like this <option value="<?php echo $row['matric_No'];?>"><?php echo $row['matric_No'];?></option>

Comment: You dont need to use `<option value="<?php echo $row['matric_No'];?>"><?php echo $row['matric_No'];?></option> ` if you are hard coding the values and not pulling the values form the database. You don't have to worry about holding the values of the dropdown menu because when you are submitting the page, it is getting redirected to `searchbook2.php` (although you written the search code with reference to the`search.php` page) with the `$_POST` array which holds all the values of the text fields and drop down menus.